# How to organize includes, scripts when developing a larger website?

Tags: php, html

I've been thinking about the best way to organize includes, scripts, css etc. in my header.php file, and I've come up with a solution but I do not know if this is even good or not. I'd like to hear your techniques regarding this matter.
I was thinking about something like this:
PS: there are more includes, but I don't want to flood this thread.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<?php if($page_title == 'Home') echo'<script src="scripts/jqplot/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>' ?>
<script src="scripts/global.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/global.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo_tab.png">
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
```

So my main idea is to put most of the optional includes in a small php script, which script would look at the current page we are on, and if that particular script is not needed it won't echo it out. Is this a viable solution?
Thanks!

Comment: That would be the first step to it. Have you ever worked with frameworks such as `Zend` or `Symfony`?

Comment: Not really, but I've just started looking into CodeIgniter because my project  is starting to get a bit chaotic.

Comment: You should try getting deeper into these and come again with a specific problem of what you are trying to achieve. These framework usually come with tools on how to properly include `JS` and `CSS` files. Look there for `Zend Framework 1.12` http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript